# Keras (2.0.8) with Tensorflow (1.3) backend takes all available RAM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ram

I am using `keras` library with `tensorflow` backend and CUDA enabled. See PIP packages versions output:

```
Keras (2.0.8)
tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.1.8)
```

I have the following code which creates `VGG16` model and loads ImageNet weights:

```
def create_vgg16_model(target_size: tuple, n_classes: int):
    base = VGG16(include_top=False,
                 input_shape=target_size,
                 weights='imagenet')

    x = base.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax', name='top')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=x)
    for layer in model.layers[:-1]:
        layer.trainable = False

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    return model
```

The model's training goes well, and `nvidia-smi` shows that GPU memory is utilized as needed. But then I've checked output of `top` command and here is what I see:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                 
 1268 ck        20   0  166288  31964  12416 S  29.5  0.1  13:05.39 Xtightvnc                                                               
32235 ck        30  10   32252   3700   3356 S   5.3  0.0   0:36.93 cwaves 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
32212 ck        20   0 27.485g 1.184g 190404 S   2.3  3.8   0:35.44 python  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                
26015 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.30 kworker/3:1                                                             
31754 ck        20   0   43168   3904   3080 R   0.3  0.0   0:04.45 top                                                                     
    1 root      20   0  185644   6204   3984 S   0.0  0.0   0:10.44 systemd
```

I have walked through the code with debugger and realized that the memory is allocated in the following function taken from `keras.backend.tensorflow_backed` which creates a `tf.Session` object:

```
def get_session():        
    global _SESSION
    if tf.get_default_session() is not None:
        session = tf.get_default_session()
    else:
        if _SESSION is None:
            if not os.environ.get('OMP_NUM_THREADS'):
                config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
            else:
                num_thread = int(os.environ.get('OMP_NUM_THREADS'))
                config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=num_thread,
                                        allow_soft_placement=True)
                # next line allocates ~28GB of RAM
                _SESSION = tf.Session(config=config)
        session = _SESSION
    if not _MANUAL_VAR_INIT:
        with session.graph.as_default():
            _initialize_variables()
    return session
```

And, this thing happens for all available models, because memory is allocated when a session created, before training has started or variables initialization.

I know that TF allocates all available GPU memory (unless you override `ConfigProto` and/or tune your environment variables), but does it do the same thing with RAM? I.e. it seems like the framework is allocating all the RAM I have on my machine, except one which is already allocated by other processes.

Does anybody spotted such behavior with different versions of `tensorflow` or `keras`? Do you think there is a way to somehow limit amount of used memory?

---

### Update 1

Some time ago one of my training scripts was killed by kernel with out-of-memory error after 50-60 training epochs. Though volatile GPU memory usage stat shows that it is used as well. (Not only allocated, as I've understood).

---

### Update 2

Agree, virtual memory is not a valid metric. But I've figured out that memory consumption is almost linearly increasing during model's training process. I have the following training loop:

```
def train_model(model, x, y):
    loss = model.train_on_batch(x, y)
    return loss


def train_model_42(model, x, y):
    # dummy function
    return 42.0


def training_loop():
    # training parameters
    target_size = 224, 224, 3
    batch_size = 128

    # generator yielding batches of file paths
    files_stream = FilesStream(folder=TRAIN_IMAGES, batch_size=batch_size)
    files_source = files_stream()

    # list of generators loading images from persistent storage
    gens = [
        image_loader(),
        augment_images(horizontal_flip=True),
        shuffle_samples(),
        normalize_images(target_size=target_size)
    ]

    # Model from keras.applications with replaced top layer
    model = get_model('resnet50').build(n_classes=n_classes)

    for epoch in range(1, 1001):
        epoch_loss = []
        for _ in range(files_stream.steps_per_epoch):
            for gen in gens:
                gen.send(None)
            processed = next(files_source)
            for gen in gens:
                processed = gen.send(processed)
            x, y = processed
            loss = train_model_42(model, x, y) # <-- this shows pic. 1
            # loss = train_model(model, x, y)    <-- this shows pic. 2                  
            epoch_loss.append(loss)
        avg_loss = sum(epoch_loss) / len(epoch_loss)
        print('Epoch %03d: train loss = %2.4f' % (epoch, avg_loss))
```

When I use dummy training function, the memory consumption plot looks like it is shown on `pic 1`:
[image]

But while running a real training process, it looks like `pic 2`:
[image]

Why the memory consumption is increasing during training process? Are previous batches of data cached or something? Should the model/weights or anything else occupy more and more memory?

I think that probably something is wrong with my data preprocessing pipeline, but I've intentionally written preprocessing functions as generators. Could it be some kind of default Keras callback applied to the model that tracks training information which is responsible for increasing memory usage?

Comment: `VIRT` field does not matter much. You should check `RES` or `%MEM` fields for the amount of memory used.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Right, agree. Now I've realized that real memory consumption is increasing during training process, and not initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I've found the root of the problem. Sure enough, it was nothing related to `tensorflow` or `keras`, but my approach to use them.

Here is a function similar to my image augmentation function:

```
def augment_images():
    transformer = ImageDataGenerator()
    while True:
        x, y = yield
        generator = transformer.flow(x, y, batch_size=len(x), shuffle=False)
        transformed = next(generator)
        yield transformed
```

It uses `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` class to augment images. But that class itself instantiates `NumpyArrayIterator` object which *keeps references* to `x` and `y` batches and calls `ImageDataGenerator` as delegate. And, that was the source of memory leak. It seems that these objects prevented arrays to be garbage collected.

Here is an updated augmentation function which uses iterator explicitly:

```
def augment_images(width_shift=0.2,
                   height_shift=0.2,
                   zoom=0.2,
                   rotation=30,
                   vertical_flip=False,
                   horizontal_flip=False):

    transformer = ImageDataGenerator()
    iterator = None

    while True:
        x, y = yield
        if iterator is None:
            iterator = NumpyArrayIterator(
                x, y, transformer,
                batch_size=len(x),
                shuffle=False,
                seed=None,
                data_format=transformer.data_format)
        else:
            iterator.n = x.shape[0]
            iterator.x = x
            iterator.y = y
        transformed = next(iterator)
        yield transformed
```

So, the problem was in generator wrappers I was using to preprocess data. (Or I would say, in my method of using Keras's API and Python's generators). At least now, when I've replaced image augmentation function, there are no memory leaks anymore.